# how convert column to row and get its row_number in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use *select* to some columns see the following example,

```
 select 55,5,8,3
```

and the result will be

[image]

---

so, how to convert this into *rows* and get the  row_number of each ? like below

```
         row.number | col_val
        ------------+--------
              1       55
              2        5
              3        8
              4        3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose [a_horse_with_no_name's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312227/3682599) is enough

or try something like this

```
select row_number() over() row_num,col_val from (
select unnest((
 select array[c1,c2,c3,c4] from (
select 55  c1,5 c2 ,8 c3,3 c4 )s 
)) as col_val) b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, 
       row_number() over ()
from unnest(array[55,5,8,3]);
```

although it is not *guaranteed* that the order is always the same (but in reality it is).

With the upcoming 9.4 version you can get a stable row number using the `with ordinality` option: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS

Comment: I wish one day on my CV I have `Certified 'a horse with no name'`

Comment: it works but I need  `array[(select 55,5,8,3)]` instead of `array[55,5,8,3]`

Comment: @a_horse: I'm guessing the real problem involves a select from a table, not just a fixed list. `unnest((select array[55,5,8,3]))` should do it.